# what size ground wire should i buy?

Tags: grounding, electrical-panel, construction, new-home, meter

I am trying to connect my house to the current meter pole that is 300 feet away I am going to buy 250kcmil for the load conductors. I know that I can save some money by buying a smaller size ground wire. I cant find a calculator to figure it out. What would be the minimum size wire that I could get for the ground wire for a 300' run?

Comment: What size is the service (in amperes)?

Comment: Does your local Code require you to run a ground wire clear out to the pole? All the work I've seen, electric service comes into the dwelling ungrounded, and the dwelling has a copper grounding rod or water-pipe bond within 5-20 feet of the panel.

Comment: What country and region are you planning on doing this installation?

Answer (score 4):

Get a copy of the local electric codes and/or contact a licensed professional in your area. The power company should also have the necessary information for what they require for a proper connection. This is not something you should DIY lightly.

This is also something where the work requires inspection from the local authorities. The power company will (rightly) refuse to connect your house if the electric installation isn't up to par.